# Hibernate/JPA merge (update) issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am getting one Hibernate exception from many days and I am not able to solve it. May be someone can help me?

I have 3 hibernate entities. (KainInka, Pvv, Pvt).

kainInka->pvv (one to many)
pvv->kainInka (many to one)

pvv->pvt  (one to many)
pvt->pvv  (many to one)

I have defined following methods in my entity classes:

1.kainInka

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "p301KainInkaId")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
public List<TP301KainInkaPvv> getKainInkaPvvs() {
    return this.kainInkaPvvs;
}
public void setKainInkaPvvs(final List<TP301KainInkaPvv> kainInkaPvvs) {
    this.kainInkaPvvs = kainInkaPvvs;
}
```

2.PVV entity class:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JoinColumn(name = "T_P301_KAIN_INKA_ID", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_PVV4T_P301_KAIN_INKA_ID"))
public TP301KainInka getP301KainInkaId() {
    return p301KainInkaId;
}


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "p301KainInkaPvvId")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
public List<TP301KainInkaPvt> getKainInkaPvts() {
    return this.kainInkaPvts;
}

public void setKainInkaPvts(final List<TP301KainInkaPvt> kainInkaPvts) {
    this.kainInkaPvts = kainInkaPvts;
}
```

3.Pvt entity class:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JoinColumn(name = "T_P301_KAIN_INKA_PVV_ID", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_PVT4KAIN_INKA_PVV_ID"))
public TP301KainInkaPvv getP301KainInkaPvvId() {
    return p301KainInkaPvvId;
}

public void setP301KainInkaPvvId(TP301KainInkaPvv p301KainInkaPvvId) {
    this.p301KainInkaPvvId = p301KainInkaPvvId;
}
```

First time persist method works perfect.

The problem is with MERGE method (kainInkaDao.merge(kainInkaObj);). I want to add new pvv objects to my existing kainInka object and that new pvv objects have new pvt objects. I am calling merge method for parent (kaininka) object. So I think it should add new entries in the database, right?

However, it throws an exception: **not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation: pvv.kainInkaId->kainInka**

Am I doing something wrong or missing some important points?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: can you provide the code where the exception occurs? Thanks!

Maybe can you upload your classes to pastebin or somewhere where I can see more?

Comment: Format your codes please.

Comment: @Ph03n1x, I am getting this exception in this method:  
    public TP301KainInka updateKainInka(TP301KainInka kainInka) {
        TP301KainInka mergedEntity = kainInkaDao.merge(kainInka);
        return mergedEntity;
    }  I have wrote this method in my bean class and used by my client.

Comment: @SAM i think code is formatted now.